# Запятая вместе с тире

Tags: пунктуация

Здесь собрались и ученые, - представители ведущих университетов и вузов, - и представители органов власти и...

Я являюсь представителем нескольких организаций, - Управления, института и университета.

Нужны ли запятые перед тире? Или как-то по-другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректно:

**Здесь собрались и ученые — представители ведущих университетов и вузов, и представители органов власти(,) и...**

**Я являюсь представителем нескольких организаций: управления, института и университета.**

или

**Я являюсь представителем нескольких организаций — управления, института и университета.**

Двоеточие — более "академический" вариант.

Примечания
 - Как уже было сказно, слово *управление* пишем со строчной.
 - Запятую перед последним *и* нужно ставить или нет в зависимости от того, что скрывается за многоточием.

Answer (score 2):

Или как-то по-другому! А именно:

*Здесь собрались и ученые - представители ведущих университетов и вузов, и представители органов власти, и..*.

*Я являюсь представителем нескольких организаций - управления (со строчной, раз нет конкретики. - *Прим. моё, Г. А*.), института и университета*.

Comment: Тире должно быть подлиннее, а так оно похоже на дефис.